# User needs to login twice

Tags: password, high-sierra, login

We're currently sampling High Sierra 10.13.1 on a few machines in the office. One of the users is getting a strange issue after a password reset.

When she reboots she's prompted for a password as usual; using the new one doesn't work. Entering the old one we get the grey progress bar, and after a while a second login-screen appears, at which she then has to enter the new password.  How do we fix this? This kind of 2FA is quite undesirable.

Cheers,
Tink

Comment: Is the second login presented as a dialog, rather than a view that takes up the entire display?

Comment: Are these 'few machines' bound to Open or Active directory authentication servers?

Comment: @Jake3231, they're both full-screen. The first one only showing the last active user, the second one also showing the admin account.

Comment: @IconDaemon, no we're not using any form of LDAP, all accounts are local to the machines.

Comment: Is the drive encrypted? idk the details of how/why, I've just read other questions here in the past where changing a login password will then present 2 dialogs, one for the encryption & one for the account.

Comment: @Tetsujin - you're right on the money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the FileVault encrypted drive is allowing the old password (first login) to unlock the drive. But, instead of automatically logging in as the same user, the password reset is causing the second login.

You will need to login to an local admin user and remove the user's ability to decrypt the drive on the command line...

```
sudo fdesetup remove -user username
```

Then add the user back in using...

```
sudo fdesetup add -usertoadd username
```

Or, with macOS High Sierra, you can use the "Enable Users" button located in System Preferences -> Security -> FileVault.

I do not know if this is normal after a password reset, but you may want to confirm that your password reset procedure is correct.

Comment: Thanks @Powerkey - I'll check that out when I get access to the machine again.

Comment: Churr. Worked a treat.

Comment: P.S.: There was no "Enable User" button on the FileVault tab =}

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe an older OS? Or, possibly, all users are already enabled?

Comment: Nope, not older; 10.13.1.  And yes, they were enabled (they had  updated from Sierra, and had been using encryption with organisation filevault before).

Comment: I managed to remove the user, but never to add it back again `Unable o add one or more users to FileVault`, so this advice was very bad for me.

Comment: in my case since there's just one user on the MacBook Mac wouldn't  let me remove the user, so I'm going to just turn it off as it's mega annoying to log in twice with two different passwords.

Comment: @Eman - if you're indeed still on HighSierra it's **high time** for an upgrade ;)

Comment: I'm on the newest version, I just happen to encounter this very issue

Comment: @Eman You can simply create a new user to use temporarily to remove/add your main user as described above. I definitely would make sure the temporary account can login from the first (FileVault) login before attempting the changes.

Comment: I'm going to just remove the Mac from AD, they make us change our password every 60 days and honestly, I can get the same benefit by using a hosts file and avoid the headaches of sync issues and double logins. I was more or less a test subject and this is something that's going to be a major issue in general and a deal breaker for most, including myself.